# C# - Make faster MySql queries?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, performance, insert

what is the best way to insert a lot of data to mysql database?

Comment: Please, have a look at `BULK INSERT`.

Comment: Hi , you can make a stringbuild and execute it one time, because you have too much IO, for example , "insert ..... ;" + "insert ......" to one string

Comment: I think I looked at some examples about strinbuild last night. is that when I loop through all my Players, and make a gigantic query, and then some `append` at the end and close it off with semi-colons? If so, then I had a lot of trouble with it. Because I couldn't insert my variables like @level, they are assigned later on at the bottom as you can see in my code. So I dont know how to do this. I find it extremely difficult with these sql queries. I sat with stirngbuild until 5am this morning, no kidding. And I just went to bed cus I was so dead tired about it. it's driving me insane

Comment: I updated my question and added my stringbuild. Please check. I dont know what I did wrong.

Comment: @willie - No, do not run "lots of inserts in a single string".  On the other hand, you can have lots of rows in _one_ `INSERT`; that _does_ run faster (like 10x).

Comment: @RickJames thanks very much for your comment , could you do me a favor to give me a small sample , how to do , thanks a lot

Comment: `INSERT ...; INSERT ...;` is essentially no faster than `INSERT ...;`, then `INSERT ...;`.  This _is_ faster:  `INSERT INTO t (a,b) VALUES (1,2), (5,6), ...;`

Answer (score 1):

You are not just doing an insert, but also using `on duplicate key update`.

I would suggest that you take a bulk-load approach:

- Put the 18-25,000 things into a file, appropriately delimited.
- Load the data from the file using `load data infile` into a staging table.
- Use the `insert . . . on duplicate key update` on the staging table.

The final step looks similar to your query:

```
INSERT INTO players (name, online, world, level, vocation, month, week, today)
    SELECT name, online, world, level, vocation, time, time, time
    FROM players_staging
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
         online = values(online), world = values(world), level = values(level),
         vocation = values(vocation), month = month + values(time),
         week = week + values(time), today = today + values(time);
```

Bulk operations are faster for two reasons.  First, they requires fewer calls into the databases -- setting up queries, returning results, and other overhead going back and forth.  Second, they reduce the amount of logging and locking required for the operations.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that type of stuff. how do i output it to a file? is it some special format? like xml? or what? i am a newbie at this, so bare in mind.

Comment: still cannot figure this out, @gordon linoff

Comment: @TibiaRook - research the term "CSV" or "Comma Separated Values" or "Tab Separated Values".  Then look for `LOAD DATA INFILE` in MySQL.  Put those two together to get high speed ingestion.  Oh, also, you need to know how to create and write a file from C#.